Multiple if-raise statement
I wrote a python code with the following format:
if a1 in list1:
    if b1 == 1 and c1>1:
        raise Exception ('invalid c1 for b1')
    elif b1 == 2 and c1>2:
        raise Exception ('invalid c1 for b1')
    elif b1 == 3 and c1>3:
        raise Exception ('invalid c1 for b1')
    else
        z = c1 * d * f
else:
    raise Exception ('invalid a1')

I performed a pylint test on my code and it shows an error that "Unnecessary "elif" after "raise". change "elif" to "if"". I did it like the following code:
if a1 in list1:
    if b1 == 1 and c1>1:
        raise Exception ('invalid c1 for b1')
    if b1 == 2 and c1>2:
        raise Exception ('invalid c1 for b1')
    if b1 == 3 and c1>3:
        raise Exception ('invalid c1 for b1')
    else
        z = c1 * d * f
else:
    raise Exception ('invalid a1')

now, pylint says "Unnecessary "else" after "raise", remove the "else" and de-indent the code inside it". I am not keen to do that because two "else" statements dealing for two different situations. I am wondering if there is any better method to implement this code that pylint won't raise any issues. (I am aware I can disable pylint errors using "#pylint disable=..." but this is not my first option)

I think pylint talks about the first "else" (inside of "if"). Removing the second "else" changes the logic.

Are you familiar with or ?

I am familiar. I think you mean I can combine multiple if-statement and change it to one if-statement using or. Sure, it works in the scenario I mentioned above. Initially my Exception messages for each "if" was case-dependent; however, in the code I mentioned above they all look similar. Anyway, thanks for the tip!

The pylint warning is about the first else, not the second. So it is suggesting to write your code like this:
if a1 in list1:
    if b1 == 1 and c1>1:
        raise Exception ('invalid c1 for b1')
    if b1 == 2 and c1>2:
        raise Exception ('invalid c1 for b1')
    if b1 == 3 and c1>3:
        raise Exception ('invalid c1 for b1')
    z = c1 * d * f
else:
    raise Exception ('invalid a1')

...which would be equivalent. The only way to get to the statement z = c1 * d * f is when the conditions in the three preceding if statements are all false.

I am wondering if there is any better method to implement this code

The above would do, but you could also save on one level of indentation by negating the first condition:
if a1 not in list1:
    raise Exception ('invalid a1')
if b1 == 1 and c1>1:
    raise Exception ('invalid c1 for b1')
if b1 == 2 and c1>2:
    raise Exception ('invalid c1 for b1')
if b1 == 3 and c1>3:
    raise Exception ('invalid c1 for b1')
z = c1 * d * f

And you can also combine conditions that lead to the same exception:
if a1 not in list1:
    raise Exception ('invalid a1')
if b1 in (1, 2, 3) and c1>b1:
    raise Exception ('invalid c1 for b1')
z = c1 * d * f


Thanks @trincot for the suggestion. Both of them were helpful.

Following to the pylint documentation, a raise Exception should not be part of an else or elif block.
According to pylint your code should look like this:
if a1 not in list1:
    raise Exception('invalid a1')

if b1 == 1 and c1 > 1:
    raise Exception('invalid c1 for b1')
if b1 == 2 and c1 > 2:
    raise Exception('invalid c1 for b1')
if b1 == 3 and c1 > 3:
    raise Exception('invalid c1 for b1')

z = c1 * d * f

